# redirection not working in python for locally hosted form snippet for cgiserver

Tags: javascript, python, cgi, python-requests

I am trying to use the following created html page to access information from a cgiserver using python. I am implementing auto redirection using javascript at bottom

```
<form action="http://pi-web.cisco.com/pims-home/fcgi-bin/BugReport/DDTS.cgi?Function=DDTS">
<input type="hidden" name="Function" value="DDTS">
By Production Build: <td valign=top>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td valign=top>
&nbsp;From:&nbsp;</td>
<td valign=top>
<select name=from_prod_build>
<option value="6_2_1_14I_DT_IMAGE" selected>6_2_1_14I_DT_IMAGE</option>
</select>
</td>
<td valign=top>
&nbsp;To:&nbsp;</td>
<td valign=top>
<select name=to_prod_build>
<option value="6_2_1_16I_DT_IMAGE" selected>6_2_1_16I_DT_IMAGE</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type=checkbox name=explicit_only value=1>
Explicit Commits Only</td>
<td valign=bottom>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" id="submit"name='by prod_bld'>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submit").click();</script>
</form>
</td>
```

However, i see in a web browser the page redirects and show the information but in python I can only fetch the created page and not redirected page. Below is the python script

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page=requests.get('http://localhost/requestDDTS.html',allow_redirects=True)
print(page.url)
tree = html.parse(page.text)
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get first page because there is no redirect.

In HTML page you have form, that is automatically submitted to `http://pi-web.cisco.com/pims-home/fcgi-bin/BugReport/DDTS.cgi?Function=DDTS`. First site returns with code 200 and not 301/302. Requests library doesn't parse javascript inside html document, it just fetches text content.

Put this in python script:

```
payload = {
    'Function': 'DDTS',
    'by prod_bld': '',  #this looks like typo, space instead of _ ?
    'from_prod_build' : '6_2_1_14I_DT_IMAGE',
    'to_prod_build' : '6_2_1_16I_DT_IMAGE'
}

page = requests.get('http://pi-web.cisco.com/pims-home/fcgi-bin/BugReport/DDTS.cgi', params=payload)
```

This should return the same page as the one you see after form submit in browser.